# Meteorjs is using sockjs instead of websockets - why?

Tags: javascript, meteor

We are currently having a problem with our meteor app.

Because of the problems with ios we changed for our Meteor app the DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS to 1. But then we had problems with our nginx so we changed it back to 0 (in our case we just removed the ENV variable from our deployment)

Since them Meteor is still not using Websockets. We have no idea why. This causes the problem that we get this error:

```
POST https://OUR_APP.COM/sockjs/632/bl2mtg76/xhr_send 404 ()
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR
```

So Meteor is using sockjs instead of websockets.

We have tested the env variable if its set correctly.

```
console.log(process.env.DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS); // logs 0
```

For deployment we are using `pm2-meteor`.

Does anyone has an idea why Meteor is forced to use sockjs instead of websockets ? We have now deployed our app several times but it does not change smth.

Btw: Websockets are - of course - enabled in my browser.

Comment: Maybe just server side or client side caching?

Comment: The files are not cached as we can see because on client and server we've added logs to test this and the logs are available.

Comment: What kind of log files are that? How do they show that you have no server side caching in place?

Comment: I am just saying that my JS files are not cached (the old state) because we changed the files and the changes are online - so its not cached (the old state) for my understanding. If smth else got cached (not the js files) could maybe be - but I dont know what this could be (we dont have nginx cache)

Comment: Ah, so you checked the content of the JS files actually loaded, not some log files for this.

Comment: I added some console.log commands to both: server and client. And both are executing the added code so the files are not in an old state

Comment: SockJS uses websockets if they are available and it is configured to use them. The real question is if there is a websocket connection to your server or is it using the XHR-based fallback.